# Databinding items control to list WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm struggling with my first real WPF adventure.

My XAML is as follows:

```
    <ItemsControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="ImageList" x:FieldModifier="private" ItemsSource="{Binding Source= images }">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- The Image binding -->
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Key}" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My C# is:

```
            var ll = new LocalDataHandler();

        var data = ll.FetchContentByContentType(
            new string[] {"Movie", "Television"}, 0);

        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> images = data.Select(
            contentItem => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(contentItem.ContentName,
                                                            contentItem.ContentId.ToString(
                                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).ToList();
        ImageList.ItemsSource = images;
```

The ImageList is populated with everything I want, but for some reason nothing displays on my form.

Comment: since you are setting ItemsSource in code behind.. there is no need of ItemsSource="{Binding Source= images }" as it is faulty code... remove the ItemsSource property in xaml

Comment: Check in the output window to see if `Key` property is being found. You say _The image binding_ in your comments but all I see is a textbox

Comment: I've got Key and Value both populated. Yet my XAML says it cannot find Key. I tried ImageList.Key, but again nothing.

Comment: @nit Removed, but no change. Thanks for helping.

Comment: add static keyvalue pairs to your list and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Binding Mode to OneWay for TeextBox

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick"></TextBox>
```